# different sized page numbers due to \usepackage{helvet}?

Tags: header-footer, fontsize, fancyhdr

I am at the end of finishing my thesis and after printing it out for final corrections I recognized that the sizes of the page numbers differ sometimes. For example page "10" and page "11". Especially when printing it out it seems to be even worse.

Here is a "minimal" example.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4 , twoside=false, 11pt, numbers=noenddot, bibliography=totoc, listof=totoc]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,USenglish]{babel}

\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{cmss}

\usepackage{type1ec}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lfoot[\fancyplain{}{}]{\fancyplain{}{}}
\rfoot[\fancyplain{}{}]{\fancyplain{}{}}
\cfoot[\fancyplain{}{\footnotesize\thepage}]{\fancyplain{}{\footnotesize\thepage}}
\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\footnotesize\nouppercase\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}{}}
\chead{}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{}]{\fancyplain{}{\footnotesize\nouppercase\sc\leftmark}}


\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}

\chapter*{Abstract}

\pagenumbering{Roman}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\newcounter{romancount}
\setcounter{romancount}{\value{page}}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Theoretical Background}
\chapter{Measurements}
\chapter{Results}

\clearpage
text
\clearpage
text
\clearpage
text
\clearpage
text
\clearpage
text
\clearpage
text
\clearpage

\chapter{Conclusion and Outlook}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{\value{romancount}}

\listoffigures
\clearpage

\listoftables
\clearpage

\addchap{List of Abbreviations}                 %adds a chapter without numerating it
\markboth{List of Abbreviations}{}          %add the name of the chapter to headings

\end{document}
```

any ideas?

Comment: Without a complete document it is hard to tell what is the problem.  However, switching the main text to sans serif should be done with `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}`.  Your command pickups up a different sans serif font to helvetica.  If you want to use the computer modern sans serif font, then drop then use my command above, but drop the `helvet` package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few problems in your code:

1. loading of `type1ec` that not only is an obsolete package, but also changes the font setup;
2. there's no point in doing setting `\familydefault` to `cmss` if you want Helvetica.

Here's a working version. The key is to say

```
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{\sfdefault}
```

that will use the sans serif family for the main text. I'd prefer `tgheros` to `helvet`, because the font is more recent and actively maintained, while still being based on the design of Helvetica.

```
\documentclass[
  paper=a4,
  twoside=false,
  11pt,
  numbers=noenddot,
  bibliography=totoc,
  listof=totoc
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,USenglish]{babel}

\usepackage{tgheros}% or helvet
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{normal}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize\thepage}%
  \fancyhead[R]{\footnotesize\scshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}%
  %%% uncomment the following line and comment the one above
  %%% if you don't want small caps and mixed case
  %\fancyhead[R]{\footnotesize\leftmark}%
}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize\thepage}%
}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}

\chapter*{Abstract}

\pagenumbering{Roman}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\newcounter{romancount}
\setcounter{romancount}{\value{page}}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\pagestyle{normal}

\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Theoretical Background}
\chapter{Measurements}
\chapter{Results}

\clearpage
text
\clearpage
text
\clearpage
text
\clearpage
text
\clearpage
text
\clearpage
text
\clearpage

\chapter{Conclusion and Outlook}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{\value{romancount}}

\listoffigures
\clearpage

\listoftables
\clearpage

\addchap{List of Abbreviations}                 %adds a chapter without numerating it
\markboth{List of Abbreviations}{}          %add the name of the chapter to headings

\end{document}
```

In order to change page style during the document it's better to define a new one.

Notice the different way I used for specifying the headers, which is easier. Remember that `\nouppercase` is a command taking an argument; you have to set the font and then say `\nouppercase{\leftmark}`. With your `\nouppercase\sc\leftmark` the `\nouppercase` was applied to `\sc` which does nothing. Also `\sc` is an obsolete command.

Comment: you are absolutely right that the fonts/use of fonts you proposed is the way to do it. My problem is, that I have worked the whole thesis with this template and I have many inkscape images with text included as .pdf_tex. When I change the font now (what changes the text width slightly) than MANY images are wired and I do not have the time to change them. Is there a way to get the page numbers right without changing the font of the whole document?

Comment: ...I have tried to change to the easier/simpler fancyhdr setup but it unfortunately changes the style and font of the header, see my updated question in the original post/question

Comment: @BenjaminMassow My setup was based on what you seemed to be wanting (footnotesize and small caps). I'll modify my answer.

Comment: maybe I am just to confused right now. The page numbering is perfect, thank u very much. But your code did not produce an header at all? Even when I changee to fancy?

Comment: @BenjaminMassow I didn't see the `\pagestyle{plain}` before the abstract. Add again `\pagestyle{fancy}` after it.

Comment: I have inserted it (and also tried to just copy your minimal example) and it does not work. There is no heading at all. Can u please update your provide minimal example?

Comment: @BenjaminMassow Now it should work